# Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 on laptop

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 18.10

I moved to Ubuntu 18.04 on 2019-01-20, and it'd been working fine until now. Now it crashes and has become unusable outside the terminal.

I reinstalled my graphics driver, and tried installing different versions, but neither resolved the issue. I then opted to reinstall the OS.

To create the bootable drive, I used **Create Startup Disk**, preinstalled on Ubuntu, and used a 64 GB flash drive.

The following occurred when reinstalling 18.04, and when installing 18.10:

- logs about `noueavu read faults`
- errors on installer startup (slideshow)
- frozen screen when `nomodeset` argument is set
- file errors on disk

I checked the disk for errors through the installation medium. This shows errors in 1 file. However, when I check on a different device, it returns that the disk is fine.

I'm confident that there is nothing wrong with the flash drive and image as:

- I followed the [How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu)
- I've used this flash drive and image to successfully install Ubuntu 18.04 on another device

Despite the issues with Ubuntu, I was able to install Windows successfully. Nothing unexpected happened during installation, and device manager detects my GPU.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong, or what would cause file errors to be found in one computer but not another?

---

### Hardware

- GPU: GTX 970m
- CPU: i7-4710HQ
- Memory: 32 GB RAM
- Storage: 512 GB SSD (SATA Samsung 850 Pro)

### Samsung Magician

SMART reports everything with the status OK.

#### Report

- Condition Good
- Written: 88.6 TB
- Firmware: Latest
- AHCI: Activated

#### Benchmark

- Read 556 MB/s
- Write 527 MB/s
- Read Random IOPS: 87,402
- Write Random IOPS: 77,636

### BIOS

- Legacy USB enabled
- XHCI Pre boot enabled
- Secure boot disabled
- CSM disabled
- Fast boot enabled

Comment: Better to disable Secure Boot since you're likely to install Nvidia drivers and those, unless manually signed, will be prevented from loading by Secure Boot. Also you should check the health of the drive where you intend to install it.

Comment: is testing booting windows installer out of the question? installing it? just to rule out this problem isn't hardware-related.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for the response. I've disabled secure boot now (no different unfortunatly), and also ran Samsung Magician while I have Windows installed and appended some information to the edit.

Comment: @tatsu Just installed Windows 10 successfully, first try and works flawlessly, and detects my GPU in device manager also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a scenario-specific answer.

The problem was that one of my RAM modules were failing.

Upon running a memory test, accessible via GRUB when booting into the installation medium, I discovered that one of my 4 RAM modules were showing errors.

I removed the offending RAM module and all issues were resolved. This would also explain the various segfaults and errors.

---

I would encourage anyone in a similar situation to test their memory. You can create a bootable flash drive with [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/), and try to boot into it on your problematic system.

As a side note, I had Corsair RAM. At the time of this answer, Corsair offered unlimited warranty in the case that a memtest shows errors, and it's impacting your system's stability. You can contact them to do an [RMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization). You'll have to verify if this is still the case at the time of reading.